# Change git Repository from Bitbucket to Gitlab In android studio

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitlab, sourcetree

I'm new to Git , I add bitbucket for my project git repository , But know for some work , I need to change my Repository to Gitlab , but i Can't , I search a lot in stack ,But they arent clear .

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the remote repository by using `git remote rm destination`. Where destination is the name given to the remote repository. Then Add the remote repository of gitlab.(say: git remote add origin ...).[Git remote remove doc](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new repository on GitLab.

Clone it on your working area. You have an empty repository. Then copy paste source from Bitbucket source to new folder. Commit an initial commit with all sources.

The issue is you loose the history.